# Como exibir caracteres separados de sequencias diferentes pulando os espaços no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quero exibir apenas os números em vermelho da sequencia, porém essa formula apenas exibi o primeiro numero especificado e o outro após dele ou antes dele, eu queria exibir dando saltos em qualquer numero especifico seja qual for sua posição, para poder usar o autopreenchimento sem problemas(clicar e arrastar o cursor para baixo), como eu faço para exibir apenas os números em vermelho ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`=ARRUMAR(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A99);" ";REPT(" ";20));41);40))`

Comment: Favor inserir a fórmula utilizada no momento como código e não como imagem.

Comment: =ARRUMAR(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A99);" ";REPT(" ";20));41);40))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solução

Com a fórmula utilizada, é possível encontrar somente valores contínuos na string.

Então é necessário encontrar o antepenúltimo valor e o último e depois concatenar, porém pode ocorrer erro quando a string não possuir espaços `" "`

### Último

Para encontrar o último valor, a seguinte fórmula é utilizada:

`=ARRUMAR(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));40);40))`

### Antepenúltimo

Para encontrar o antepenúltimo valor, a seguinte fórmula é utilizada:

`=ARRUMAR(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));120);40))`

### Concatenação

Então são concatenadas com:

`=ARRUMAR(CONCAT(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));120);40);ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));40);40)))`

### Verificação

Verifica se há mais do que dois espaços na célula com:

`=SE((NÚM.CARACT(A2)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A2;" ";"")))>1;"Fórmula caso haja mais que dois espaços";"ERRO")`

## Fórmula

`=SE((NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"")))>1;ARRUMAR(CONCAT(ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));120);40);ESQUERDA(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(""&ARRUMAR(A1);" ";REPT(" ";40));40);40)));"ERRO")`

> As versões de Excel mais novas utilizam a função `CONCAT()` e as antigas `CONCATENAR()`

Comment: Inseri a ultima formula e deu: "#nome?" com as duas primeiras funcionou, eu acho que o Excel já devia vim com uma função de selecionar caracteres separados e definir a posição a nossa escolha

Comment: Verifiquei agora, o "Concat" estava abreviado, depois eu inseri certo, funcionou a formula! grande, mais funcional